# ActiveX Registration

Tags: activex

I'm working on an ActiveX where the same code base should be used to two different ActiveXs, meaning, I have the single solution which is built from several DLLs.
When I build the solution for creating the CAB for ActiveX A, I change the DLLs class IDs to specific ones and when I built it for creating the CAB for the second ActiveX, I changed the class IDs to something else.

I need both ActiveXs to be able to run on the same machine.
Basically, it works fine except for that in certain scenarios where I run different versions of the ActiveXs (ActiveX A is from older code version than ActiveX B) there is un-desired behavior.
It looks like that ActiveX loads some DLLs from ActiveX B (which is from different code version).

Sorry for the long description but last important information, since both ActiveXs come from the same code, I have the same class name which is exposed to the javascript which calls the ActiveX.
In the registry there is total separation in all keys except for the following (NetworkInterface is the exposed class):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyActiveX.NetworkInterface\CLSID]
@="{31ED2205-F6AE-4133-AD30-60CA2783ADA6}"
```

When installing ActiveX I see this entry with the right class ID but when installing the second ActiveX the key is overridden by the second ActiveX.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?
Is there any way to have the same class registered with different class IDs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Lior, You answered your question yourself in this phrase: "to have the same class registered with different class IDs". In fact, we are talking about ProgID's, or programmatic identifiers - MyActiveX.NetworkInterface in your case.

There is just one dedicated registry hive for ProgID's - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\, and if you use a ProgID in your client code to instantiate a component, you can do it only for one ActiveX component. When you create an instance using a ProgID, the corresponding CLSID is determined using that registry hive, and the executable DLL/OCX/EXE which implements that class is used. For the latter case, the corresponding registry hive looks like this:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\Clsid{6935DB93-21E8-4ccc-BEB9-9FE3C77A297A}\InProcServer32

The best thing which can be done in this case is to use two different ProgID's for your two ActiveX components. Even if you use the same source code for the main classes, you can use them "as is" in two different projects which are used to compile components with separate ProgID's. It seems, all dev environments (VB6 you're maybe using) allow you to do that.

Some more info about this can be found in this article: http://www.vbaccelerator.com/progid.htm

We had the same issue with our ActiveX components, and our experience tells us that to have different ProgID's is the best choice. Even if you release a next version, change the ProgID. This will allow both versions to coexist in the same OS without any problems, and the developers can upgrade the existing projects step-by-step.

===

As an answer to your question, I have an idea of how you can try to solve your problem if you cannot change ProgID's. As I know, you can activate ActiveX's using directly their CLSID's, and different dev environments use different techniques for that. I do not have your project, but if you use JavaScript, you can try the recipe from this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/08652e9e-7deb-40a3-8c1a-f9becdcbf56e/

In a nutshell, you do not need to create your ActiveX objects using a call like this:

```
myobject = new ActiveXObject("SAMPLEACTIVEX.sampleActiveXCtrl.1");
```

You need to put your two ActiveX controls on the page using the OBJECT tag and call the methods of your objects using their names (id's) on the webpage. If you look at an example of the HTML OBJECT tag, you'll see something like this:

As you can see, you can use the specified ID to access the members of the object you exactly need. Many examples of that are already on SO - here is one of them:

[javascript: "Object doesn't support this property or method" when ActiveX object called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458578/javascript-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-when-activex-object)